# How can I create a real "reveal page" slide effect

Tags: slide

I've been searching for a way to do this effect: http://www.discovershadow.com/

Especially the iPhone reveal part at the bottom where the iPhone stays but the content inside changes at the same time as the background.

Can this be achieved with only css or is it something much more complicated?

Comment: did you tried anything ???

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I found to do this... no one seemed interested in the question but I hope you like the answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
html, body { 
    min-height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
} 

#container { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    position: fixed;
}

.items { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 102%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative; 
} 

#box1 { 
    background-image: url(yourimage1.png);
    background-color: #03F; 
}

#box2 { 
    background-image: url(yourimage2.png);
    background-color: #609; 
} 

#box3 { 
    background-image: url(yourimage3.png);
    background-color: #3C0;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container"> 
<div class="items" id="box1"></div>
<div class="items" id="box2"></div>
<div class="items" id="box3"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes can achieve that... You have not added any code or not even tried i think. Here is simple code for you to get you started.

```
.a
{
    background-image : url('http://hdwallpaper2013.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Beautiful-Nature-Images-HD-Wallpaper.jpg');
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
p
{
    color : #000;
    font-size: 72px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/7zKE2/)

Answer (score 0):

This effect does require CSS + Javascript, there is no way to do it effectively without using these technologies. You could have the iPhone centred on screen and the rest of the screen move around it but it wouldn't create such as nice effect as seen on the website.

I would personally recommend looking at the source of the target website and investigate yourself how it was achieved, never hurts to have a sneek peek at source from other websites.

Looking at that sites script.js page they handle scrolling with

```
// handle scrolling
    $window.scroll(function() {         
        handleScroll();
    });
```

Which does this. You will need to look at the full code to work out exactly how its done.

```
// handle scroll
function handleScroll() {

    scrolledWin = getPageScroll();
    $body.addClass('scrolling');    

    // show logo
    if((scrolledWin * 1.5) > winH) {
        $body.addClass('content');
    }

    // show navigation 
    if(scrolledWin > 50) {
        $body.addClass('scrolled');
    }

    // app img animation
    if(topOff >= scrolledWin) {
        $appImg.removeClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $appImg.addClass('sticky');
    }
    if(topOff2 >= scrolledWin) {
      $appImg2.removeClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $appImg2.addClass('sticky');
    }

    // fix navigation issue on top scroll
    if ((scrolledWin > -(winH - (winH * (f1 *0.8)))) && $('#hook2').hasClass('inViewport')) {
        $nav.attr("class", "").addClass('a2');
    } else if ($('#hook2').hasClass('inViewport')) {
        $nav.attr("class", "").addClass('a1');
    }

    //fix navigation issue between how it works and next section
    if ($s9.hasClass('inViewport')) {
        if ($('#hook5').hasClass('inViewport')) {
            $nav.attr("class", "").addClass('a5');
        } else {
            $nav.attr("class", "").addClass('a4');
        }
    }

    //fix navigation issue between Experts and next section
    if ($sExperts.hasClass('inViewport')) {
        if ($('#hook6').hasClass('inViewport')) {
            $nav.attr("class", "").addClass('a6');
        } else {
            $nav.attr("class", "").addClass('a5');
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.discovershadow.com/js/script.js?v=2.14